# Silverlight: Add border around grid

Tags: c#, silverlight, grid, border

I have a grid that I need to put into a border, doing this via XAML is easy
but how do I do this via C#?
everything that I have found thus far wants to add the border around each cell.

I need it to come out looking the same way XAML does it, please help!

I can not get the XAML to post correctly here:

```xml
<Border Grid.Column="1" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Background="AliceBlue" 
        BorderBrush="Black" 
        BorderThickness="4" 
        x:Name="Side6" 
        Visibility="Collapsed">
    <UIElement.Projection>
        <PlaneProjection RotationY="-90" />
    </UIElement.Projection>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Click="RotateRight_Click">
            <Button.Content>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Rotate Right</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">To</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Side 4</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Click="RotateLeft_Click">
            <Button.Content>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Rotate Left</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">To</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Side 2</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   Grid.Column="1" 
                   Grid.Row="1" 
                   Text="Side 6">
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

---

Here is the C# code that I'm using, maybe you can see what I am doing wrong?

```
public static void panelMain(string strPassGridName, System.Windows.Media.Color mcPassColor, 
int intRowProperty, int intColumnProperty, Visibility vVisibility, 
string[] strButtonTitles, Grid passLayoutRoot, Canvas passCanvas)
    {
        Grid panelGrid = new Grid();

             panelGrid.Name = strPassGridName;
             panelGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(mcPassColor);

             panelGrid.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, intRowProperty);
             panelGrid.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, intColumnProperty);
             panelGrid.Visibility = vVisibility;

        RowDefinition row1 = new RowDefinition();
                      row1.Height = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Auto);
             panelGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row1);

        ColumnDefinition column1 = new ColumnDefinition();
                         column1.Width = new GridLength(100);
             panelGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column1);


        passLayoutRoot.Children.Add(panelGrid);
    }
```

Comment: Obligatory: Can you show us what you tried in C#?

Comment: Did you see [Child](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.decorator.child.aspx) property?

Comment: yes and that is where is tells me that it is already a child

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I needed to create the border first then add the grid to the border.
One major difference is that I could not reference the border object directly, I needed to "find it"

```
   Border findBorder = passLayoutRoot.FindName("bd" + strPassGridName) as Border;
   if (findBorder == null)
   { }
   else
   {
     findBorder.Child = panelGrid;
   }
```

This worked perfectly....
Thanks to all that attempted to help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below,

```
        Border gridBorder = new Border();
        gridBorder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        gridBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(4);
        gridBorder.Child = new Grid(); //Your grid here
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(border); // ParentGrid(layout) holding the border
```

Comment: sorry that did not work, I get "Element is already the child of another element."  If I change the last line a little, I get one square in my grid to have a border 
Border gridBorder = new Border();
                   gridBorder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                   gridBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(4);
                   //gridBorder.Child = panelGrid; //Your grid here
                   panelGrid.Children.Add(gridBorder);

Comment: Your last line panelGrid.Children.Add(gridBorder); wont work. You need add the gridBorder as a child of root grid, shown as below. LayoutRoot.Children.Add(border);

Comment: I must be missing something, how do I get the border to wrap around the grid?  This line (gridBorder.Child = new Grid();) says to add the new grid but how do I make a reference to the grid that is being created

Comment: here is the c# that I am using, maybe you can see what I am doing wrong?